# Change ItemIndex in a Comobox when drop down list is open

Tags: c#, combobox, windows-mobile, compact-framework

In Compact Framework, I want to change the ItemIndex of a ComboBox when the drop down list is open. I am trying to change it from LostFocus or KeyPress events, and it seems to work, but when the drop down list is closed, the value returns to the original value.

For example:

```
    private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab)
            return;
        if (e.KeyChar == 'A')
        {
             e.Handled = true;
             comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
        }
    }
```

When I press A, effectively the item #2 is selected and the text, but when I move to th next control or simply close the drop-down list, the combobox changes the value the previous one.

Thank you

Comment: Try subscribing to the SelectedIndexChanged event and logging the stack trace there to see who is changing the value when you close the combo.  You can use try { throw new Exception(); } catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e.StackTrace); } to print the stack trace.

Comment: The trace does not help too much. It seems to me that SelectedIndex cannot be changed at KeyPress event:  SmartDeviceProject1.Form1.comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e)
System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)

Comment: Have you tried using SelectedValue property instead (or with) SelectedIndex?

Comment: What is the text in item 2 of your combobox?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried to replicate your issue (but running on FF) with the following code and it is working fine:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace combotest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            WinForm form = new WinForm ();
            Application.Run (form);
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    public class WinForm : Form
    {
        public WinForm ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
        }
        ComboBox comboBox1;
        TextBox textBox1;
        private void InitializeComponent ()
        {
            this.Width = 400;
            this.Height = 300;
            this.Text = "My Dialog";
            Button btnOK = new Button ();
            btnOK.Text = "OK";
            btnOK.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (10, 10);
            btnOK.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (80, 24);
            this.Controls.Add (btnOK);
            btnOK.Click += new EventHandler (btnOK_Click);
            comboBox1=new ComboBox();
            comboBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (10, 50);
            comboBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (80, 24);
            comboBox1.DropDownStyle=ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            this.Controls.Add (comboBox1);

            textBox1=new TextBox();
            textBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point (100, 50);
            textBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size (80, 24);
            this.Controls.Add (textBox1);

            this.SuspendLayout();
            String[] iList=new String[]{"text0","text1","text2","text3","text4"};
            comboBox1.Items.AddRange(iList);
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex=0;
            this.ResumeLayout();            
            comboBox1.KeyPress+=new KeyPressEventHandler(comboBox1_KeyPress);
        }

        private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Tab)
                return;
            if (e.KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper() == "A")
            {
                 e.Handled = true;
                 comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2;
                textBox1.Text=comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            }
        }
        private void btnOK_Click (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close ();
        }

    }
}
```

So I assume you are having some additional code or event attached to the comboBox or it really behaves different within FF.

You may test your app also running within FF by just going to the bin\Debug dir within your PC's file explorer and then start your SmartDevice application on the PC by double clicking the exe file. Normally (no special DLLs referenced) it should run on PC too as the CF is downside compatible to FF.

If you still have an issue please post a minimized code sample that demonstrates your issue.